# Python 3.5 programs suddenly don't work after Anaconda installation

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip, anaconda

I am bugged by installing too many dependencies for Matplotlib on python 3.5. I tried most conventional matplotlib module installers but problem lingered. So I installed Anaconda (3.4) so mpl comes along with it. Great! it worked! But when I returned to my Python3.5 programs, most don't work anymore. For example, lxml and other modules don't work and install. When I tried to revive pip-install.py, it even cannot compile due to errors such as missing modules. I made sure that paths are correctly set. I tried to "Repair Errors" python 3 and pip worked fine. However, pip doesn't install any kind of modules now. The same [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57An1.png) shows up always.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just create a conda environment for your py35 program, like this: `conda create --name py35env  python=3.5` and then `conda install` whatever packages you need into it.

Answer (score 0):

As previously commented you can create a separate environment with Anaconda running a different version of python as follows and include the package you want:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 matplolib
```

I am not sure what you meant by when you return to your Python 3.5 programs. Just to be sure are you aware that Anaconda installs its own python binaries in it's own location, usually your user directory. This will keep any Anaconda python modifications separate from your system python if you have it. This means if you install python 3.5 and matplotlib with Anaconda it will not be found using a system python.